# Running Jest tests loop forever

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

Today, for some unexplained reason my jest test files started looping, resulting in a flickering terminal.

I am running `jest src --watch`, src being my source folder.

I followed a number of other discussions but none of them have helped solve my issue.

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4635  is talking about a custom processor, but I am using a default setup.

I have tried ignoring folders.

I have ended up removing all my test files, at which point the looping stops.  If I add a test file to `__tests__` it matches the file but does not run a test.  If I add the test file to my /src folder, it starts looping again, and it doesn't matter if the actual test passes or fails. Even if I add a fake test with a simple

```
describe('Test Suite', () => {
  test('two plus two is four', () => {
    expect(2 + 2).toBe(4)
  })
})
```

it loops and flickers.

This is my jest setup

```
  "jest": {
    "verbose": false,
    "watchPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/dist/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "globalSetup": "./jest-setup.js",
    "globalTeardown": "./jest-teardown.js",
    "testEnvironment": "./jest-mongo.js"
  },
```

Does anyone know what is causing this to loop? I am not changing any files in any folder to make the --watch think it needs to run again, there are no other apps i.e. dropbox syncing the folder.

I am developing in VSCode, but the same thing happens if I test in a terminal window.

This was running fine just 5 hours ago, what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the jest.setup file was writing a configuration file to disk, while setting up a temporary mongoDB. If at least one of the tests used the mongoDB the looping stopped, or if I removed the setup files the looping stopped.

So my problem started when out of 30 test files, the one that connected to mongo was edited (starting the looping/flickering). In trying to solve the problem I removed all the rest of the test files, which left me with the most basic tests, but still the looping because I was still not connecting.

Still not 100% sure of the exact mechanism, but when inheriting someone else's codebase which doesn't use the default jest setup, probably best to expand jest knowledge to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out my own version of this issue, posting for anyone else who may come across this. I had to add a specific json file `globalConfig.json` to my `watchPathIgnorePatterns`.

```
"watchPathIgnorePatterns": [
   "<rootDir>/globalConfig.json",
],
```

No idea why this file vs the `jest.json` referenced here: https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/5038

EDIT: it's because I'm using `jest-mongodb`. See https://github.com/shelfio/jest-mongodb#6-jest-watch-mode-gotcha